# Efficiency in Metropolis Vs Gibbs sampling

Tags: bayesian, gibbs, metropolis-hastings

I have read that Gibbs sampling is more efficient than Metropolis algorithm. Why? Is this due only to the fact the in Gibbs sampling the acceptance rate is $1$, so that the chain needs fewer iterations to converge with respect to Metropolis?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim?

Comment: I read it on Doing Bayesian Data Analysis - 2nd edition

Comment: In what context is the claim? I think in general that is not the case. E.g.in some hierarchical models Gibbs sampling allows to use the structure in the model efficiently and can thus can be fast. However, with e.g. many multidimensional nonlinear models, Metropolis-Hastings is more efficient since the conditional densities for Gibbs sampling cannot be computed in closed form and the correlations decrease efficiency. How efficient Metropolis-Hastings is depends also on how good proposal you can design for it in particular case.

Comment: There is no general theory behind this claim, because Metropolis is too general a method to state such things. Gibbs sampling is not very efficient because it changes one component at a time, hence moves in a rather correlated manner. It thus has difficulties in jumping between well-separated modes.

Comment: Checked the book quickly and on p. 162 the authors state "The Metropolis method is very useful, but it can be inefficient. Other methods can be more efficient in some situations. In particular, another type of sampling method that can be very efficient is Gibbs sampling". So note the "in some situations" and "can be"!